# i got a runtime error as "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo" what would be the reason?

Tags: android, instantiation

I am trying to run a listfragment prog during that i got the below error in log cat and the emulator shown Force close in alert box.  Can any one solve the problem please....

> **ERROR:** 02-09 07:24:55.633: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(517):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   instantiate activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.android.Frags/com.android.Frags.FragsActivity}:
>   java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.android.Frags.FragsActivity cannot
>   be cast to android.app.Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make your activity extend Activity class.

```
public class FragsActivity extends Activity
```

Also you really shouldn't use com.android as part of your namespace.